# VBA | How can I make a Macro Sheet Specific

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a workbook with several introductory sheets followed by ten data sheets labeled "'1'", "'2'" etc. The macro is meant to do the same thing for each page, but the variable [A0] could change for each data sheet (a value ranging from 5 to 7). I would like to make the macro page specific so that I could create a button (on a seperate tab called "Inputs") that would process the macro without the user needing to visit tab "'2'".

(The purpose of the multiple buttons is to allow the user to only use 3 of the tabs if needed, because the excel program that I have created for the rest of the workbook can take about 5 minutes to execute.)

```
Sub InsertCells()

    Dim lastColCell As Range
    Set lastColCell = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, A0 As Long
    k = 0
    'A0 = Flowback Constant
    A0 = Sheets("Wells").Cells(2, 20)
    For i = 6 To lastColCell.Column
        Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(7 + k, i + 2)).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        k = k + A0
        'Each A0 should correspond to a different cell if user has different flowback delays
        i = i + 2
    Next i

End Sub
```

This code was created by user @BryceWayne and works very well - but unfortunately I have had trouble adding this final feature.

Comment: Fully qualify all of your `Cells`, `Columns`, `Rows`, `Range` references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fully qualify all of your `Cells`, `Columns`, `Rows`, `Range` references. Easiest way to do this on a small procedure would be to wrap it in a `With` block:

```
Sub InsertCells
    Dim lastColCell As Range
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, A0 As Long

    A0 = Sheets("Wells").Cells(2, 20)   ' Flowback Constant

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'Modify as needed
        Set lastColCell = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
        k = 0
        For i = 6 To lastColCell.Column
            .Range(.Cells(3, i), .Cells(7 + k, i + 2)).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            k = k + A0
            'Each A0 should correspond to a different cell if user has different flowback delays
            i = i + 2
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

It's a little unclear why you're doing `For i = 6 to lastColCell.Column` and then incrementing `i=i+2` within  that loop. That appears to be effectively incrementing `i` by 3 at each iteration (2 because of the `=+` and then one more because of `Next`.  You would be better to do:

```
        For i = 6 To lastColCell.Column Step 3
            .Range(.Cells(3, i), .Cells(7 + k, i + 2)).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            k = k + A0
            'Each A0 should correspond to a different cell if user has different flowback delays
        Next i
```

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned the `i = i + 2`!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but here's an easier way that you can use with or without editing the code manually.

Start on a different tab when you record your macro.  First thing you do is switch tabs, and it'll add this line:

```
Sheets("Sheet Name").Select
```

You can keep switching sheets and it'll automatically apply the changes to each sheet in sequence, without having to fully qualify the names, and without the macro running on the specific sheet the user happens to have open.

Similarly, you can manually enter the command above anywhere you want within your code, if you want to write the code instead.